# How do I require a resource in a Puppet definition based on an array parameter?

Tags: linux, puppet, ruby

I have a define that looks like this:

```
define user::sys_user($fullname, $uid, $groups, $shell='/bin/bash', $authkey, $authkey_type=rsa) {
        $username = "sys_${name}"
        group { $username:
                gid =>  $uid,
        }

        user { $username:
                require => Group[$username],
                ensure => present,
                uid => $uid,
                gid => $uid,
                groups => $groups,
                comment => $fullname,
                shell => $shell,
                managehome => true,
                allowdupe => false,
        }

        ssh_authorized_key { "${username}_authkey":
                user => $username,
                ensure => present,
                key => $authkey,
                type => $authkey_type,
        }
}
```

In the `user` resource, I am requiring the user's default group. I also want to require supplemental groups if provided by the parameter $groups.

Also, is the way I do `groups => $groups` going to fail if it's empty or if it's just a string (i.e., defines just one group instead of an array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `groups => $groups` is likely to fail. It may not fail here in particular, but this particular pattern is not safe.

Put an `if` statement testing whether it is set or not, and define `user` with and without it on the `if` and `else` bodies.

Comment: so just `if $groups` be enough to check if it's `nil`? Also can I make the `$groups` parameter optional by doing `define user::sys_user(..., $groups = nil,...` in the definition?

Comment: As far as I know, no, that is not enough.

Comment: What about if the default value for groups is an empty array?  `define user::sys_user(..., $groups = [],...`